# How to parallelise a loop with a return statement?

Tags: c#, loops, parallel-processing, return

I have a written a Bitmap extension method that will search for "this" Bitmap inside another Bitmap and if found will return the Point at which it is found. The algorithm works by searching the rows of the larger image line by line. I would like to split the rows into as many sections as there are cores on my machine, and search them asynchronously. If one of the threads finds the image, the other threads need to be cancelled. Can this be achieved with a parallel for?

```
public static Point LocateWithin(this Bitmap smaller, Bitmap larger) {

        if (smaller.Width > larger.Width || smaller.Height > larger.Height)
            return new Point(-1, -1);

        Rectangle smallerRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, smaller.Width, smaller.Height);
        Rectangle largerRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, larger.Width, larger.Height);

        BitmapData smallerData = smaller.LockBits(smallerRectangle,
                                                  ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                  PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        BitmapData largerData = larger.LockBits(largerRectangle,
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        try {
            IntPtr largerPtr = largerData.Scan0;
            IntPtr smallerPtr = smallerData.Scan0;

            int smallerStrideLessOne = smallerData.Stride - 4;
            int smallerHeightLessOne = smaller.Height - 1;
            int heightDiff = larger.Height - smaller.Height;
            int widthDiff = larger.Width - smaller.Width;

            for (int yl = 0; yl <= heightDiff; yl++) {
                for (int xl = 0; xl <= widthDiff; xl++) {

                    if (memcmp(smallerPtr, largerPtr, smallerData.Stride) == 0) {

                        IntPtr lPtr = largerPtr;
                        IntPtr sPtr = smallerPtr;

                        bool isMatch = true;
                        for (int ys = 0; ys < smallerHeightLessOne; ys++) {
                            lPtr += largerData.Stride;
                            sPtr += smallerData.Stride;
                            if (memcmp(sPtr, lPtr, smallerData.Stride) != 0) {
                                isMatch = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isMatch)
                            return new Point(xl, yl);
                    }
                    largerPtr += 4;
                }
                largerPtr += smallerStrideLessOne;
            }
        }
        finally {
            smaller.UnlockBits(smallerData);
            larger.UnlockBits(largerData);
        }
        return new Point(-1, -1);
    }
```

Comment: When you complete this I would be interested in knowing how much performance you gain. Seems like given that this is so I/O intensive you would have a bottle neck reading the image from main memory any way and i wonder how much threads buy you here... Im not doubting they would buy you something, just legitamtly curious how much.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple shared bool "hasBeenFound" be sufficient? Make sure to check regularly, as well as right before returning.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't think the smaller image crossing a row division will be an issue since the threads will still have access to all rows in the larger image even if they only iterate over a section of them. Checking for a shared hasBeenFound bool from all threads will do the job nicely, thanks for the suggestion. I will post my results when I have made the changes.